# Accessing the VS2010 version of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine assembly in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assemblies, visual-studio-2012, lint

My company recently created a Visual Studio 2010 add-in that allows us to create LINT files from any given visual studio project from 2010, 2008 and 2005. We now want to get this same add-in to work in Visual Studio 2012, because we know that many of our customers will be using this in the near future, if not already.

We thought that it should be a simple "switch-in", and that the same code should work for both, but lo and behold, the VS10 add-in didn't work in VS12. So I copied the code (**absolutely no changes**) into a VS12 add-in, and surprise surpise, it did work. Naturally, we do not want to have two versions of the same code; bad for readability, bad for maintainability, so we still want to find a way to get the VS10 add-in to work in VS12.

I think the problem lies in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine assembly. This is interpreted differently in VS12 to how it was in VS10, meaning that when VS12 reads the add-in, it doesn't do what we want it to do.

I have done some research into this problem, and many people suggest creating a work around by using reflection, but I am reasonably new to this concept and don't feel confident enough to try it and risk seriously ruining the add-in.

So my question is this: Is there a nice and easy way of being able to read the VS10 version of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine into VS12?

Much appreciated :)

Comment: Alternatively, If you know of any reason other than this assembly that two add-ins with exactly the same code (one for VS2010, one for VS2012) work in their respective Visual Studios but not in the other, that would also be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later found an answer to this question and realised it hadn't been confirmed on the thread.

The answer indeed lies in the VCProjectEngine assembly. For some reason, this is a different module in Visual Studio 2010 to the module (with the same name) in Visual Studio 2012, which means any code requiring the module when written in VS2012 will not work in VS2010 and visa-versa.

It's a pain, because it means we have two lots of exactly the same code, but that is the way it has to be.

Comment: One approach to solving the duplicate code issue is to add links to the source files instead of copying them to the second project.

Comment: You could use `dynamic`s to get rid of the duplicate code. You'll lose compile checks though.